# Build app with multiple build variants of library in android

Tags: android, android-library, android-productflavors

I have created a library called mylibrary with two product flavors like virtual and nonvirtual like below

```
flavorDimensions "dev"
productFlavors {
    virtual {
        dimension "dev"
    }
    nonvirtual {
        dimension "dev"
    }
}
```

and I have implemented the library in my project LibraryTesting like below

```
implementation project(path: ':mylibrary')
```

Now, when I trying to select different build variant its showing errors like "Module 'LibraryTesting.mylibrary' has variant 'nonvirtualDebug' selected, but the module 'LibraryTesting.app' depends on variant 'virtualDebug'"

please find the below image for more information

[image]

I want change the library build variant and build the app with that selected variant.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `app` module must decide what flavor to use.

For example, if you want `app` module to compile `myLibrary` module and `virtual` flavor, you need to add the following to `android.defaultConfig` block in `build.gradle` of `app` module:

```
missingDimensionStrategy 'dev', 'virtual'
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to choose the variants from UI without errors, you can create 2 flavors in `app` module and each flavor will compile the corresponding flavor in `myLibrary` module:

```
flavorDimensions "app_dev"
productFlavors {
    virtual {
        dimension "app_dev"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'dev', 'virtual'
    }
    nonvirtual {
        dimension "app_dev"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'dev', 'nonvirtual'
    }
}
```

**In any case, `app` module must declare missing dimension strategy**